# pwd without symlinks

Tags: symlink

If I do `pwd` I notice it uses whatever symlinks I used to get into the current directory.  Can I get it to tell me the "real" directory I'm in ... i.e. the path from the root to my current directory without the use of any symlinks?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

According to the POSIX manpage for `pwd`, the `-P` option may be of use:

> -P     The absolute pathname written
>   shall not contain filenames that, in
>   the context of the pathname, refer to
>   files of type symbolic link.

Thus

```
$ pwd -P
```

should be what you need.

Comment: I would like to point out that this information is easily found by typing `man pwd` in shell to find out options for this command.

Answer (score 9):

The pwd shell built-in uses the path the shell keeps track of when you `cd` (and stores it in `$PWD`). This means if you have a symlink to a complex (deep) path, it will tell you what you typed to change to that directory instead of the real path. This is done to give you what you want most of the time.

`/bin/pwd` uses the `getcwd` system call (which these days is a library call, reading `/proc/self/cwd`) which returns the canonical path for the current directory, sans all symlink traversals.

As Steven D pointed out, `pwd` has the `-P` option to ignore `$PWD`. It also has the `-L` option to return the contents of `$PWD`. The man page for `pwd` does not say which option is used by default but experience tells me the above description is correct (shell `pwd` vs. `/bin/pwd`). However you should probably not rely on that and just use `pwd -P`.

Comment: The behavior you describe is the one on Linux systems where `/bin/pwd` is GNU `pwd` when POSIXLY_CORRECT is not set. On POSIX systems where the `pwd` is in `/bin`. `/bin/pwd` will use $PWD and may return paths with symlinks. GNU pwd will behave in that POSIX manner when it find a POSIXLY_CORRECT variable in its environment.