# pwd resolving symbolic links

Tags: directory, symlink

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [pwd without symlinks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6800/pwd-without-symlinks)

Imagine I have a directory

```
/home/me/dir
```

and a symbolic link to it called

```
/home/me/dirlink
```

now if I enter `dirlink` and use `pwd`, it of course prints the 2nd one. Is there a flag to make it resolve the symlink and print the 1st one?

Answer (score 1):

Either try /bin/pwd or try pwd -P

Comment: oops, read Mat's comment above too late... sorry.