# Path resolution depending on pwd (symlinked dirs)

Tags: bash, symlink, path

This sort of situation often occurs under the `/sys/bus` tree (bash-5.1) :

Let's say I get some `foo` directory listing several symlinks to other directories, `ls -ails pathto_foo` displaying something of the kind :

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 21 foo1 -> whatever relative path to symlinked foo1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 21 foo2 -> whatever relative path to symlinked foo2
```

Each one of these symlinked dirs containing a regular file named `bar` :
If I change my present working directory to `pathto_foo/foo1` or `pathto_foo/foo2`, I can `file`, `stat`, `cat`… `bar` without trouble.

However, my pwd being set to `pathto-foo/foo1` (or `pathto_foo/foo2`), sat-ing/c-ating/file-ing `../foo2/bar` (`../foo1/bar` respectively) will systematically return :

```
../foox/bar : No such file or directory
```

OK! I can, at some extreme limit understand and accept this utmost unwelcome behaviour, however, I just neither understand nor accept the following inconsistency :

If, sitting in anyone of those two directories, let's take `pathto_foo/foo1`, I want to stat/cat/file `../foo1/bar` (**yes! I do mean a relative path to the pwd**) I'll be successful.

So why does the path resolution depend on the pwd ? (why are relative paths to the pwd resolved differently to other similarily written  relative paths ?)
How can I prevent that and get an identical answer (successful or unsuccessful) irrespective of the pwd ?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6800/pwd-without-symlinks

Comment: @JRFerguson : Fair enough! I still fail to understand the difference in the path resolution. Why is the path resolution identical when cd-ing to ../foo1 and ../foo2 and why is the path resolution different when stat-ing ../foo1/bar and ../foo2/bar. I would have expected consistency at least from a syntactical standpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A directory can have multiple symlinks pointing to it, but it has only one real parent directory, which has nothing to do with the symlinks.

So your `/sys/bus/pathto_foo` contains two symbolic links:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 21 foo1 -> /sys/some/where/foo1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 21 foo2 -> /sys/else/where/foo2
```

When you are `cd`'d at `pathto_foo`:

- your `cat foo1/bar` maps to `cat /sys/some/where/foo1/bar`
- your `cat foo2/bar` maps to `cat /sys/else/where/foo2/bar`

When you then do a `cd foo1`, your real working directory will not be `/sys/bus/pathto_foo/foo1` but actually `/sys/some/where/foo1`, although the shell (**and only the shell**) will remember that you referred to it as `/sys/bus/pathto_foo/foo1`.

Now if you do a `cat ../foo1/bar`, `..` refers to `/sys/some/where/`, and since both the symbolic link and the actual directory it points to were conveniently named `foo1`, the full path will be `/sys/some/where/foo1/bar`, as expected.

If you try `cat ../foo2/bar`, it now maps to `/sys/some/where/foo2/bar`, but there is no `foo2` subdirectory in `/sys/some/where`.

The actual `foo2` was at `/sys/else/where/foo2` which is in a different branch of the directory tree altogether.

And the symbolic links you used to arrive here were in `/sys/bus/pathto_foo`, which is **not the actual** `..` of `/sys/some/where/foo1`.

When you do a `cd ..`, the default for modern `bash` and most POSIX-compatible shells is do a **logical** shift to parent directory, i.e. *cut off the right-most element of the path the user used to arrive at the current directory, and then change to that path*.

Most other programs will understand the concept of "parent directory" simply as "the `..` directory entry provided by the filesystem", which refers to the directory's **physical** parent.

The `cd` command of `bash` actually has two options, `-L` and `-P`, to explicitly request either logical or physical interpretation of the path to switch to. If you don't specify either option, the built-in default is to behave as if `-L` was specified, and so do as described above. If the `-P` option is used, the `cd` command will behave just like all other programs and will change to the physical parent directory whenever `..` is used.

If you don't like this (mis)feature of the shell, there is probably a shell-specific way to disable it. With the `bash` shell, adding `set -P` or `set -o physical` to your `~/.bashrc` or similar shell start-up script would make bash behave like all cd commands had the `-P` option unless the `-L` option is explicitly used.